# CSS and embed video resizing

Tags: html, css

I am retrieving video embed urls from my database.

In my database, my videos are 600x450. What I want to do is make them smaller and place them within a `<td>`. In order to accomplish this, I wrote the following CSS with template lite tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
{literal}
  div.embed
  {
    width:  200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
{/literal}
</style>
```

My markup follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>Fragmanlar</td>
  <td>
    <div class="embed"/> 
      {foreach value=movieF from=$movieFragman}
        {$movieF.embedCode} 
      {/foreach}
    </div>
  </td>                
</tr>
```

The problem is that my video sizes are not being affected, and it runs over the edges of my `<td>`.

image:

[image]

Comment: What does `<div class="embed"/>` mean?

Comment: maybe because you are closing `div` here: `<div class="embed"/>`

Comment: Can you show the resulting HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot target the container of the videos themselves, you would need to target the actual video element. If they are within `div.embed`, you can amend this selector for specificity:

```
div.embed video {
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

This, of course, assumes you're using the HTML5 [`video`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106#_HTML5_video_audio) tag. If you are not, you may need to target either `embed` or `object`, depending on how you display your videos.

For example, you may have something like the following:

```
<object width="560" height="315">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/NWHfY_lvKIQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

You could target both the `object` and its `embed` child:

```
div.embed object,
div.embed embed {
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

On another note, your opening tag shouldn't self-close, as this may cause problems identifying nested elements within.

```
<div class="embed">
  <video...>
    <source... />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: @MertMETİN Then you will need to target `embed` or `object`; whichever your video code uses. Also, please consider using HTML5 video tags in the future for maximum support across browsers/devices :)

Comment: i use div.embed video {
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
}  but this does not make smaller video :S

Comment: @MertMETİN If you provide us an example of what your embed codes look like, we can give you more specific selectors to use in your CSS.

Comment: <embed src="http://www.abc.com/images/player2.swf?video=173350&amp;movieid=1500" wmode="window" bgcolor="#000000" allowfullscreen="true" scale="noScale" width="640" height="483" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> This is embed code . and In template lite i retrieve this code    <td><div class="embed" > 
             {foreach value=movieF from=$movieFragman}
            {$movieF.embedCode} 
            
            {/foreach}
      
      
      </div></td>

Comment: @MertMETİN You'll want to target the `<embed/>` with your CSS selector. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you accidentally closed your div to early by using `<div class="embed" />`. You wanted `<div class="embed">` instead. (note the lack of the forward slash)

```
<tr>
    <td> Fragmanlar </td>
    <td>
        <div class="embed"> 
            {foreach value=movieF from=$movieFragman}
            {$movieF.embedCode} 
            {/foreach
            }
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: still same , it runs over from div

Comment: You may want to see Jonathan's answer then.